# How to transpose character data for unique IDs

Tags: r, transpose

Im trying to perform a sum function to count the number of interactions for Unique Id's

So I have something like this:

```
Client ID    
JOE12_EMI    
ABC12_CANC
ABC12_EMI
ABC12_RENE
```

and so on...

It'll also have a column next to it that counts the how many times each unique ID repeats.

```
Frequency
1
2
2
1
```

Is there a way that i can have all the activity types (EMI, TELI, PFL) summed for each ID and then placed into new columns?

I've tried to transpose the data by separating the actual ID from the activity type but this doesn't return the sums, thank you for any help. I'm not sure if that's the best way or if transposing the data to wide format and then doing another sum function but I am unsure how to go about it.

```
separate(frequency, id, c("id", "act_code") )
nd <- melt(frequency, id=(c("id")))
```

Comment: Is `Frequency` a column that you already have that tells you the frequency of an `id` + `act_code` combination, or a column that you want to add that tells you how many records have that `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
data=data.frame(Client_ID= c("JOE12_EMI",
                             "ABC12_CANC",
                             "ABC12_EMI",
                             "ABC12_RENE"), 
                frequency= c(1,2,2,1))

client_and_id <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(data$Client_ID), "_")))
names(client_and_id) <- c("client", "id")

data <-  cbind(data, client_and_id)

data_sum <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(sum_freq = sum(frequency))
```

The output

```
> data_sum
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   id [3]
  Client_ID  frequency client id    sum_freq
  <fct>          <dbl> <fct>  <fct>    <dbl>
1 JOE12_EMI          1 JOE12  EMI          3
2 ABC12_CANC         2 ABC12  CANC         2
3 ABC12_EMI          2 ABC12  EMI          3
4 ABC12_RENE         1 ABC12  RENE         1
```

You can also display the output by ID:

```
distinct(data_sum %>% dplyr::select(id, sum_freq))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    sum_freq
  <fct>    <dbl>
1 EMI          3
2 CANC         2
3 RENE         1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track; I think the only thing you need is a `group_by`.  Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df = data.frame(ClientID = c("JOE12_EMI",
                             "ABC12_CANC",
                             "ABC12_EMI",
                             "ABC12_RENE"))

df %>%
  separate(ClientID, into = c("id", "act_code"), sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(frequency = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(id, act_code) %>%
  mutate(act_frequency = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(act_code, act_frequency)
```

(This does the sum by user and the pivot by activity type separately; it's possible to calculate the sum by user after pivoting, but this way is easier for me to read.)